# Find the geometric position of all points satisfying the two equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: circles

Find the geometric position of all points satisfying the two equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=1$

I think the points for which their coordinates satisfies the two equations at the same time,are all on a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ such that the distance between the circle and the origin is $\pm \sqrt3$.

Comment: Isn't the second a cylinder? Even if it were a circle - the distance of any point on it to origin is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ represent a sphere with origin $O$ and the $r=2$

$x^2+y^2=1$ represent a cylinder with Orgin $O$ and the $r=1$

[image]

If the center of the sphere lies on the axis of the cylinder of revolution, then the intersection curve degenerates into two circles.

The equation of intersection( 2 circles) is:

$x^2+y^2=1 , z=\pm \sqrt3$

Comment: I edited answer and write the equation

Comment: If $x^2+ y^2= 1$ and $x^2+ y^2+ z^2= 4$ then $1+ z^2= 4$ so $z^2= 3$ and $z= \pm\sqrt{3}$.   That is, the cylinder (not circle) intersects the sphere (as Soheil said) where $x^2+ y^2= 1$ and $z= \pm\sqrt{3}$.  We can parameterize those two circles as $x= cos(t)$, $y= sin(t)$, $z= \sqrt{3}$ and $x= cos(t)$, $y= sin(t)$, and $z= -\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$2$ circles in fact, and the parameterized equations are $f(t) = (t, \pm \sqrt{1 - t^2}, \sqrt{3})$ and $g(t) = (t, \pm \sqrt{1 - t^2}, -\sqrt{3})$. So you are pretty close.

---

Then you can see these 2 circles are actually the parallels (horizontal strips on any sphere) at $60 \deg$ north and south from the equator of the sphere with radius of $2$ units and center at the origin $(0, 0, 0)$.

See my finger illustration for why $60 \deg$.[image]